# How can I make VS Code recognize typescript declarations between mono-repo packages?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, parceljs

I have a mono-repo project configured with an isolated library package (TS only) and another web UI package (TS + React).

I am importing the compiled library package from the consumer (web UI) package. To do so, I am using yarn to link the packages and parcel to generate the library package's distribution files.

Parcel is automatically generating a `d.ts` file in the library package's `dist` folder.

I am using the VS Code as IDE and when I open the consumer packages file that imports the library and make use of it, the VS Code is not recognizing the types declared in the library package's `d.ts` file.

This is the packages' structure:

```
rootPackage
|- library
|- web-ui
```

In the `library` package, I have a `types.ts` file and an `index.ts` file. There is only a single type being exported:

```
export type ParamType = "a" | "b" | "c";
```

I'm using `parcel watch` on this package to automatically refresh the `dist` files when something is changed.

Parcel is generating the `main.d.ts` file just fine and this file is being referenced by the `package.json`'s `types` attribute.

When I try to use this `ParamType` type by the `web-ui` package's code, I got the following IDE error highlighting in the type:

```
Cannot find name 'ParamType'.ts(2304)
```

When I run parcel in the `web-ui` package, it compiles just fine and the browser is loaded with no problems/warnings.

I think it's a problem related exclusively to the VS Code and I'm not sure how to fix it.

---

#### Edit 1

I've created a [public repository on GitHub](https://github.com/brunoalvesdefaria/TypescriptMonoRepo) to demonstrate the issue.
If you know how to fix it, feel free to create a pull request, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you share a simplified reproduction in a github repo? One thing to be aware of is that Parcel doesn't do type-checking by default unless you configure the [@parcel/validator-typescript plugin](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/#experimental-validator-plugin) - so it might not be a VSCode-specific problem. What happens when you try to type-check the web-ui project with `tsc`?

Comment: Hi @AndrewStegmaier, I've just edited the question adding a reference to the repository. About running tsc, I haven't created the tsconfig.json files. After trying it quickly, I got the error: `src/App.tsx:6:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ParamType'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your [example repo](https://github.com/brunoalvesdefaria/TypescriptMonoRepo), the root of your `library` package looks like this:

**/shared/lib/src/index.ts**

```
import { ParamType } from "./types";

const Library = {
  typedParamMethod(param: ParamType) {
    console.log(param);
  },
};

export default Library;
```

And the way you're consuming the `library` package in your `web-ui` package is is like this:

**/ui/web/src/App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Library from 'library';

function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const typedParam: ParamType = 'b'; // VSCode and tsc throw the error "Cannot find name 'ParamType'." 
    Library.typedParamMethod(typedParam);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="web-ui">Web UI</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that you are neither exporting `ParamType` from to root of your `library` package, nor importing it into your `web-ui` package. Modern JavaScript and Typescript modules are isolated from each other - the `import { ParamType } from "./types"` line in your `library` package root makes `ParamType` available *in that file*, but it doesn't affect (or pollute) the global namespace of something that happens to import *something else* (e.g. the default export) from the `library` package.

To solve the problem, add this line to the `library` package root (e.g. `/shared/lib/src/index.ts`):

```
export { ParamType } from "./types.ts";
```

And then modify the import from your `web-ui` package (in `/ui/web/src/App.tsx` to this:

```
import Library, { ParamType } from 'library';
```

(The problem and solution are unrelated to VSCode - anything that tries typecheck the `web-ui` package will emit the same error, without these changes)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that out!
I didn't know I needed to export all the types like this.